# Source for Moses' life divided into 3 parts of 40 years

Tags: sources-mekorot, moshe-rabbeinu

I am looking for a source (Gemara? Midrash?) that says that Moshe Rabbeinu's life was divided equally in 3, first forty years in Egypt, then 40 years in Midyan and 40 years in the desert with the Bnei Israel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sifre ([n. 357](https://www.sefaria.org/Sifrei_Devarim.357.33?with=all&lang=bi)):

> ומשה בן מאה ועשרים שנה - זה אחד מארבעה שמתו בן מאה ועשרים, ואלו הם: משה והלל הזקן ורבן יוחנן בן זכאי ור' עקיבא. **משה היה במצרים מ' שנה, ובמדין מ' שנה, ופירנס את ישראל מ' שנה**